# LUNS access issue in ESX4 Cluster server

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

HI,

I've created volumes in equallogic in PS 6000 XV(having 2 member which is in 1 pool), checked & those volumes can be easily
detected my ISCSI software in windows.

But the problem with ESX , not able to see the assigned disk on ESX server, I can explain what I've done:

1.>Created Cluster with enabled HA & DRS
2.>Added 3 ESX4 HOST
3.>Added VMkernel & configured in all 3 ESX4, enabled vmotion & FT on the same adapter.
4.>went to iSCSI storage adapter properties, enabled iSCSI
5.>Trying to discover the available storage with the controller IP on dynamic discovery, but not able to see the assigned storage

Note: the same volume is accessed to windows that means there is no issue from storage , am I right ????

Note: I wanted to mount the same volume in all 3 ESX host.

Please suggest ....

Thanks & Regards,
Rashid Mustafa

Answer (score 1):

One other thing you could check on the Equallogic volume settings is that the volume is configured to allow multiple initiators to connect at the same time.  If the Windows Test server is connected and only a single initiator connection is allowed, then the ESX Servers wouldn't be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Group IP address as the iSCSI target, you say you are using the controller ip address but I assume that's not the case because you can see the storage in Windows.

I'd try modifying your VMKernel ports\vSwitches so that vMotion and FT are not shared with iSCSI on the same physical NIC. It might be OK for testing but it's certainly a bad idea for production.

Double check the ip-settings for the VMKernel port in VMware. From the ESX command line use `vmkping` to test that you have kernel network visibility between the ESX hosts and your Equallogic array - for good measure test that you can ping the Group IP address and the ip-addresses of all of the Equallogic arrays' active Nics ( that will be Eth0 to Eth3 on each array).

In the Equallogic Group Manager check that you haven't specified restrictions on the volumes that prevent the ESX host seeing the storage - you want to add either the ip-addresses of the VMKernel ports or the iQN's of the VMware iSCSI Software adapter for this, you do not want to use the FQDN of the ESX hosts because that will resolve to the Service Console ports which wont work.

You'll probably want to disconnect the volume(s) from that Windows Test server too.

Answer (score 0):

As you mounted the volume through Windows, be sure it's not using it anymore (fully unconfigured). Even if you remove the access from Equallogic, the PS6000 doesn't break the existing connection